# Max nchar from two strings in matrix

Tags: r

I'd like to find out better approach for finding greater nchar of two strings which I'm comparing with each other.

Let say I have strings in **sentenceMatch** data.frame and I need to create a matrix of max(nchar(string1), nchar(string2)) but without for loop which is very slow approach.

```
sentenceMatch <- data.frame(Sentence=c("hello how are you",
                                   "hello how are you friend",
                                   "im fine and how about you",
                                   "good thanks",
                                   "great to hear that"))

sentenceMatch$Sentence <- as.character(sentenceMatch$Sentence)

overallMatrix_nchar <- matrix(, nrow = dim(sentenceMatch)[1], ncol = dim(sentenceMatch)[1])

for (k in 1:dim(sentenceMatch)[1]) {
  for (l in 1:dim(sentenceMatch)[1]) {
    overallMatrix_nchar[k, l] <- max(nchar(sentenceMatch[k, ]), nchar(sentenceMatch[l, ]))
  }
}
```

Is there any better solution how can I speed up this computation? Thanks a lot for any of your help in forward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `outer`:

```
nc <- nchar(sentenceMatch[[1]])
outer(nc, nc, pmax)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   17   24   25   17   18
[2,]   24   24   25   24   24
[3,]   25   25   25   25   25
[4,]   17   24   25   11   18
[5,]   18   24   25   18   18
```

Comment: 33 times faster than the loop/apply solution. Nice.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik OP runs `nchar` twice in each iteration with no reason. Other than that, eventually you will get out of memory for a big enough vector with `outer`. I think a simple `sapply` could be safer in this case.

Comment: David, how can I implement sapply function in case of my example, please?

Comment: @SmithiM you don't need to compute both triangles of your matrix because they are identical, so you can easily reduce this to half of computations while not loading the whole data into memory at once. For instance: `len <- length(nc) ; sapply(1:len, function(x) pmax(nc[x], nc[x:len]))`

Comment: However, the `sapply` is likely substantially slower since it is not as highly vectorized.  Also it does not return a matrix and involves more code.

Answer (score 4):

```
sentences <- c("hello how are you",
               "hello how are you friend",
               "im fine and how about you",
               "good thanks",
               "great to hear that")
sn <- nchar(sentences)
n <- length(sn)
M1 <- matrix(sn, n, n)
M2 <- t(M1)
(M1 + M2 + abs(M1 - M2)) / 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   17   24   25   17   18
# [2,]   24   24   25   24   24
# [3,]   25   25   25   25   25
# [4,]   17   24   25   11   18
# [5,]   18   24   25   18   18
```

where I use the fact that max(x, y) = (x + y + abs(x - y)) / 2. Very similar performance:

```
set.seed(1)
sentences <- replicate(paste0(rep("a", rpois(1, 3000)), collapse = ""), n = 1000)

f1 <- function(sentences) {
  sn <- nchar(sentences)
  n <- length(sn)
  M1 <- matrix(sn, n, n)
  M2 <- t(M1)
  (M1 + M2 + abs(M1 - M2)) / 2
}

f2 <- function(sentences) {
  nc <- nchar(sentences)
  outer(nc, nc, pmax)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(sentences), f2(sentences))
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  f1(sentences) 33.39924 37.66673 57.9912 42.45684 82.01905 122.5075   100   b
#  f2(sentences) 31.59887 34.97866 50.5065 37.82217 77.82042 103.6342   100  a
```

Comment: Really very smart approach. Thanks a lot for inspiration. The performance is roughtly the same as G. Grothendieck's approach.